# how to make a variable case insensitive?

Tags: python

I want change the below code to run the command `adb -s %s get-state"%(adb_id)` such that the adb_id is made **case-insensitive**,it should work  if the adb_id is `1281b6a1` or `1281B6A1` ?can anyone provide guidance on how to do that?

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
#adb_id = '1281b6a1'
adb_id = '1281B6A1'
cmd = r"C:\adb -s %s get-state"%(adb_id)#cmd  = os.getcwd() + "\\adb devices"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(output,error) = proc.communicate()
#Check if adb detects any devices
if error !=  '':
    print "ERROR:%s"%error
else :
    print "Provided Id is found in ADB as ", output
    print str ( output ).strip()
```

Comment: Isn't that up to whatever `adb` is? I mean, you could be consistent about always giving all-lower- or all-upper-case, but surely it's up to that program?

Comment: if the correct id's are always completely uppercase you can always convert your `abd_id` to uppercase with the `upper()` method

Comment: @jonrsharpe and rbierman - I have a scenario where it can be uppercase or lowercase

Comment: `adb` is the Android Debug Bridge (used with Android phones) and Android device IDs can have any characters and are case-sensitive. There is no way to make `adb` itself case-insensitive without recompiling it. So you will want to grab the output of `adb devices` to get the correct casing for the device name. Better yet, let the user choose from a menu (or auto-choose if there is only one device). In other words this is not really a Python question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. What scenario? Why can it be uppercase or lowercase (and if it can be uppercase or lowercase... why do you care if it's uppercase or lowercase)?

Comment: @kindall - I understand but I have a requirement which I need to satisfy  where it can be uppercase or lowercase

Comment: You don't control the device name so you don't know what case the device name needs to be in order for it to be accepted by `adb` and there's nothing you can do from the Python side to make `adb` case-insensitive. Like I said, fish it out of `adb devices`.

Comment: kindall - It sounds like a reasonable request,it is possible to have multiple devices connected to a host and possible to have device ids in different cases, its good to have such checks for less errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make `adb` case-insensitive, so if you want the user to be able to enter the device ID without worrying about case, you'll need to find the *correct* case of the device's name and pass that to `adb`.

And to do that you'll need to get the output of `adb devices` to find the device's actual name. Then find what the user entered in that device list using a case-insensitive search, and finally return the canonical device name from that.

```
devlist = subprocess.check_output("adb devices")
devname = "\r\n%s\t" % adb_id.lower()   # device name is followed by tab
posn = devlist.lower().find(devname)
if posn + 1:      # found
    adb_id = devlist[posn+2:posn+2+len(adb_id)]
else:
    print("that device is not connected")
```

Now `adb_id` is the *case-corrected* version of the device ID and can be passed via `subprocess` to `adb`.

A better solution is probably to use the output of `adb devices` to make a menu. That way the user doesn't have to type the full device name.

Comment: thanks kindall ,this is exactly what I was looking for, `case correctness`can you please explain me the code...why are we doing `posn + 1` ?what does `posn` contain

Comment: `posn` is the result of `str.find()`. It is -1 if the substring was not found. So `posn+1` is *zero* if the string was not found, which makes it handy for `if`.